# Load webview URL from other VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I'm trying to make it work but nothing.
I want to make (URL textfield) on (RightVC) as (webview)-url on (LeftVC).

I saved the textfield with this code:

```
@IBAction func save(sender: UIButton) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(urltxtfield.text, forKey: "urltxtfield")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("urltxtfield") != nil {
        urltxtfield.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("urltxtfield") as? String
    } else {
        urltxtfield.placeholder = "urltxtfield"
    }
}
```

And it's ok with save. But how to make URL work with LeftVC webview?

This pic to make you understand me:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your LeftVC (webView), you first need to get the `NSUserDefaults` and then make a request with your `webView`.

```
let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let url = prefs.stringForKey("urltxtfield"){
    // You have an URL and can make the request
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)      
}else{         
   // Nothing stored in NSUserDefaults         
}
```

**Update**
After I got the project I updated the reference to the webView from `strong` to `weak` and I added the temporary code

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

In info.plist to allow you to browse on websites (you have to check if you want this and I can recommend you to read more about it).

Comment: `-[__NSArrayM loadRequest:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb412d97ca0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[__NSArrayM loadRequest:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb412d97ca0` I got this

Comment: On which line? Can you upload your project and I´ll take a look at it.

Comment: @asd3344, could you upload it to Dropbox or Google Drive instead?

Comment: that's it in google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3qYooQadxK4UjB2NnNEOTM1dUE)

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tg19cfmex3r61s4/WebView.zip?dl=0) is a working project. I´ll update the answer with the thing I had to correct @asd3344

Answer (score 0):

here:
 some sample of code to call load request to `UIWebview` when user enter url that `urlstring` it pass here as parameter Instead of `google.com`:

```
UIWebView.loadRequest(webviewInstance)(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "google.cam")!))
```

OR

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.google.com");
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
```